# drawing an outline pie (chart)?

Tags: android, graph

I have found achartengine, androidplot, but noone can create something like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the legend you could try [holographlibrary](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary). This library has that option for displaying pie charts. You just need to implement that legend by your own. By the way I will do this soon too.

[image]